# Should I include a job that lasted a week on the resume?

Tags: job-search, new-job, first-job

A few months back I started my first job, but I quit within a week.

Once I started working I was very excited to be there but my coworkers were very toxic. I didn’t feel comfortable working there. I was and still am a minor and I felt uncomfortable being around people my age who smoked and used drugs, and occasionally offered them to me. Even people who were of age.

It’s been a few months since I quit and I feel comfortable to start looking for another job. Should I put my previous job on my resume? Or should I leave it out of the application?

I feel that this job will be a better environment for me to work in and I feel more comfortable in my abilities to handle those types of situations.

Answer (score 2):

> Should I put my previous job on my resume?

Given that you were only there for a *week* I would not recommend to include such brief (and negative) experience on your resume.

Usually a "worthy" experience to include are those that you had for *at least* 6 months, as those are better seen in the eyes of potential recruiters (as they might suggest work and professional stability, or similar).

As you can see, "one-week experiences" like the one you had are not the best kind, and usually denote that something went wrong during that work relationship (either from your behalf or the company's) thus why one would prefer to leave them outside your resume.